# Custom React Hook on Ctrl+S keydown

Tags: reactjs

I do apologise in advance as I'm still new to ReactJS. I'm fooling around with eventListeners on keyboard press's and I've come across an example of a custom hook being used on handling keypress's. I've tried refactoring the code to suite my needs but I'm unable to do so. Currently I have the eventListener assigned on checking for the "Enter" key being pressed, but I'd like to change it to the use of "Ctrl+S" being pressed instead, how would I go about doing that and if a short explanation could be provided, I'd really appreciate that. I understand that keydown would be suited best, But I'm unable to get it working.

here is what I have:

```
function useKey(key, cb){
    const callback = useRef(cb);

    useEffect(() => {
        callback.current = cb;
    })


    useEffect(() => {
        function handle(event){
            if(event.code === key){
                callback.current(event);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keypress',handle);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("keypress",handle)
    },[key])
}

function App() {

const handleSubmit = () => {
   alert('submitted')
}

useKey("Enter", handleSubmit)

 render (
   <div>....</div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To capture ctrl+S what you need is `e.ctrlKey` along with `e.code === 's'. So here is a little modification:

```
function useKey(key, cb){
    const callback = useRef(cb);

    useEffect(() => {
        callback.current = cb;
    })


    useEffect(() => {
        function handle(event){
            if(event.code === key){
                callback.current(event);
            } else if (key === 'ctrls' && event.key === 's' && event.ctrlKey) {
                callback.current(event);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown',handle);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown",handle)
    },[key])
}

function App() {

const handleSubmit = () => {
   alert('submitted')
}

useKey("Enter", handleSubmit)
useKey('ctrls', () => console.log('Ctrl+S fired!'));

 render (
   <div>....</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's not being triggered. Since I'm making use of Ctrl+s, how would this keypress be read then? is it ideal to use keypress instead of keydown on ctrl press events?

Comment: @MuddledRanger21 Sorry,my bad, the actual code for key S is `event.code==='KeyS'`.. I got confused with the key, which actually is `event.key==='s'` :)

Comment: and yes, you should actually use a `keydown` here, as the `keypress` event is triggered only by pressing a key that produces a character..

Comment: Thank you, it's working & happy new year :D

Answer (score 0):

### it is different solution but works for me

```
function App() {
  function handleKeyDown(event){
    if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === "s") {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default browser behavior (saving the webpage)
      // Call your custom function here
console.log("ctrl + s pressed")
  }

 render (
   <div
onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
>....</div>
 )
}
```